# Get number of cores on a XP 64 bit system

Tags: windows, autoit, system-information

Hej,

I wrote a function that should give me the number of cores of a windows system. It works on all systems except XP 64 bit. Here's the way I get the information:

```
$objWMIItems = $objWMIService.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
If (0 == IsObj($objWMIItems)) Then
       ;~ errorhandling
Else
For $objElement In $objWMIItems
    $nCoreNumber = $objElement.NumberOfCores
Next
```

Regarding "NumberOfCores", Microsofts MSDN page tells me "Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000:  This property is not available". Somewhere I read, it is possible with having SP3 installed. I suppose that's true, because it works that way on XP 32 bit systems. But there is no SP3 for XP 64...

Is there another way to get the information?

Thanks

Comment: There is a reason even Microsoft don't support 64-bit XP for their products (Office 2010), it is an incomplete platform.  Just ignore it :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's easiest to read the NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS environment variable.

Comment: MsgBox(0, "", EnvGet("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"))

Answer (score 0):

Do you want "cores" or "number of logical processors including hyperthreading"?  (In other words, do you want to count hyperthreading as a "core")?

In any case, copying [my answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from a similar question a while back:

> If you actually need to distinguish between actual cores, chips, and
>   logical processors, the API to call is
>   [GetLogicalProcessInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
>
> [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381%28VS.85%29.aspx) if just want to know how many logical processors on
>   a machine (with no differentiation for hyperthreading.).

Comment: I just realized the person asking the question wants a scripting solution and the API usage I threw out was for C/C++/C# programming. So maybe this answer isn't that good.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, if the solution is for C/C++/C#. Knowing a bit about the "C-languages" I can convert that to AutoIt ;). I simply wanted to know, if it's a single, dual, quadcore processor. So I'll try with the API you suggested. Thanks